# Why is toggling the dropdown when I click enter key on input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If I type something in the first input field and then click the enter key the dropdown is being toggled, why is that happening?

If the onClick event is inside the button why the input field is toggling the dropdown?

I've tried to find out with no success yet,
Any suggestion will highly appreciate.

Index.js

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ToggleButton>
        <DropDownMenu />
      </ToggleButton>
      <div>
        <input
          onclick={(e) => console.log(e)}
          placeholder="Search Movie"
        />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="submit" value="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you have `<DropDownMenu />` inside `<ToggleButton>` in `index.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you have a button in a form and the form treats the button as a submit button (meaning its `onClick` handler function is treated as the form's submit function). Because of this, when you press Enter in the input, form submission is invoked and the form calls the `onClick` function of the button, thus toggling the dropdown menu.

To fix this you can add the prop `type="button"` to the `<button>` element to tell the form that the button is just a normal button and not a submit button.

Alternatively, you can move the dropdown menu and button outside of the form, but I'm assuming that's a more invasive change than you'd like.

Here's an example of what you currently have:

```js
function CurrentExample() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); console.log("form submit")}}>
            <input type="text"/>

            <button onClick={() => console.log("button click")}>Click</button>
        </form>
    )
}

const root = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(<CurrentExample/>, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

And an updated example using `type="button"`:

```js
function FixedExample() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); console.log("form submit")}}>
            <input type="text"/>

            <button type="button" onClick={() => console.log("button click")}>Click</button>
        </form>
    )
}

const root = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(<FixedExample/>, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```